# WPF log4net is not writing to the log file

Tags: wpf, log4net

I have a WPF solution. I downloaded log4net dll, I added log4net.config and had set the "Copy to Output Directory" value as "Copy always".

**log4net.config:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="myapp.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

And I added the below line in **AssemblyInfo.cs:**

```
  [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

then the below code in my **TestWindowControl.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class TestWindowControl : UserControl
        {
            private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

            public TestWindowControl()
            {
                XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo("log4net.config"));
                log.Info("info testing");
                log.Debug("debug testing");
                log.Error("error testing");
                log.Fatal("fatal testing");
                log.Warn("warn testing");
            }
        }
```

But logs are not writing to the file. It's working in Console application but not working for WPF. Am I missing something?

Comment: Where are you creating an instance of your TestWindowControl?

Comment: Havent created an instance yet. Passing file path to the appender file param <file value="${TMP}\myapp.txt" /> is writing logs to the file. But when I install this extension and execute logs are not writing to the file.

Comment: If you haven't created an instance the code in the constructor haven't executed...

Comment: Created an instance in VSPackage.cs file -> "MenuItemCallback". Now logs are writing to the file when I run in local but in the server, it's not happening.

Comment: Server? How is a UserControl related to a server?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the filter inside appender

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
  <levelMin value="WARN" />
  <levelMax value="ERROR" />
</filter>
```